# Find arrray intervals that add up to a given value

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to create a method that finds intervals within an array that add up to 13

example:
{10,0,3,0,1,1,1,10,5,5,5}

0 and 2 add to 13

0 and 3 add to 13

3 and 7 add to 13

4 and 7 add to 13

EDIT: this is the output I'm getting

interval 0 and 2 is 13

interval 0 and 6 is 13

interval 2 and 9 is 13

This is what I tried:

```
public static void findSum (int[] arr) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;
    int resu = 0;

    while (i < arr.length-1) {
        if (resu == 13) {
            j++;
        }
        resu = arr[i] + arr[j];   
        while (j < arr.length-1 && resu < 13){
            j++;
            resu = resu + arr[j];   
        }
        if (resu == 13){    
            System.out.println("interval " + i + " and " + j + " is 13");
        }
        if (resu != 13){
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Sorry, just edited it. The output I'm getting is wrong, so I need some help fixing this method.

Comment: it is simpler if you're using `for` loop rather than `while` loop

Comment: The answer you marked as helpful is less efficient as you unnecessarily check sums that don't need checking and you invoke a third loop that is also not needed. MV_81 I see you don't like my answer anymore but why would you mark this particular answer as helpful and not @hakim ? If you can use a for loop (I tried tweaking your approach which is why I used while) his answer is much better than the one you marked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void findIntervalSumOf(int sum, int[] values){
    for (int i = 0, size = values.length; i < size; i++){
        int currentSum = values[i];
        for (int j = i+1; j < size; j++){
             currentSum += values[j];
             if (currentSum == sum) {
                System.out.println(String.format("start: %d end %d", i, j));
             } else if (currentSum > sum) {
                break;
             }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you had some issues with declaring variables in wrong places as well as unnecessary conditional statements. This should do it for you..

```
public static void findSum (int[] arr) {
    int i = 0;


    while (i < arr.length-1) {
        //define resu and j on the inside as these change with every i
        //start j from the i+1
        int j = i+1;
        //define resu as the ith element
        int resu = arr[i];
        //keep adding to resu until we have reached end of array or until resu is greater than the target  
        while (j < arr.length-1 && resu < 14){
            //add the jth element of the array
            resu = resu + arr[j]; 
            //print if we have a match
            if (resu == 13){    
                System.out.println("interval " + i + " and " + j + " is 13");

            }
            j++;
        }
            i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code has been tested with your example of the question

```
public class TestArray {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {10,0,3,0,1,1,1,10,5,5,5};
        findSum(arr);
    }

    public static void findSum(int[] arr) {

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            int sum = 0;
            sum += arr[i];
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                sum += arr[j];
                if (sum == 13) {
                    System.out.println("from=" + i + " to=" + j + " the sum is=13");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The result is:

```
from=0 to=2 the sum is=13
from=0 to=3 the sum is=13
from=3 to=7 the sum is=13
from=4 to=7 the sum is=13
```

I hope it is useful

Comment: Why do you track sum inside the second loop? This forces you to add that third loop which is not needed. Check out @hakim 's answer to see what I mean

Comment: You're right, I've improved the code. Thank you @LucasKot-Zaniewski

Comment: But now it's literally the same as @hakim 's so what is the added value of this answer?

Comment: your commentary adds no value and his answer came before yours, plus your answer was initially of low quality. Hakim's answer uses two loops...read it again. It's actually still better than yours because it breaks out of the loop if there is a match.